# Is there a way to edit a javascript function to live update in a html form output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written a working absence calculator using a HTML form and a javascript function. Unfortunately I need this to update to the output in real time and I cannot figure out how to do it without firing the function multiple times.

HTML

```
  <form id="absence-form">
    <div class="input">
      <div id="title">Absence Calculator</div>

      <div id="firstCell">
        <div id="instruct">
          Enter number of employees:
        </div>
        <input id="employees" type="text" name="employees">

          <div id="secondCell">
            <div id="instruct">
              Enter average salary:
            </div>
          </div>
          <input id="salary" type="text" name="salary">

          <div id="thirdCell">
            <div id="instruct">
              Enter absence %:
            </div>
          </div>

          <input id="absence" type="text" name="absence">
      </div>

      <div id="instruct">
        <div id="output">Total salary (£):
        <div id="totalSalary">
        </div></div>
          <div id="output">Monthly absence cost (£):
          <span id="monthlyAbsence">
        </span></div>
        <div id="output">Annual absence cost (£):
        <span id="absenceCost">
        </span></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript Function

```
function multiply() {

  var employees = document.getElementById('employees').value;
  var salary = document.getElementById('salary').value;
  var totalSalary = parseInt(employees) * parseInt(salary);
  var result1 = document.getElementById('totalSalary');
  result1.innerHTML += totalSalary;
  var absence = document.getElementById('absence').value;
  var absenceCost = parseInt(totalSalary) / 100 * parseInt(absence);
  var result2 = document.getElementById('absenceCost');
  result2.innerHTML += absenceCost;
  var monthlyAbsence = parseInt(absenceCost) / 12;
  var result3 = document.getElementById('monthlyAbsence');
  result3.innerHTML += monthlyAbsence;
}
});
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Also, how do you call your function?

Comment: What's the problem with calling the function multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to bind your function to the change event for the input elements.

This can be done a couple of ways:

Obtrusively (*not recommended*) with the element's `onChange` attribute ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0gfr9n6/5/))

Non-obtrusively (*preferred*) with `.on('change', function() {} })` ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0gfr9n6/6/))

I'm assuming from the tag that you're using jQuery but you can achieve the same thing with vanilla JS using `.addEventListener('change', callback, false)` ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0gfr9n6/7/))

Comment: Also, notice that in the linked fiddles I changed where you use .innerHtml from `+=` to `=` (I commented the original lines for comparison). Using `+=` causes the updated value to be appended to whatever is already there instead of replacing it.

Comment: Thanks for the += tip, that was another problem I was having.

The EventListener doesn't seem to be firing in browser. I'd already tried this and assumed I'd done it wrong, any ideas why it wouldn't be? The .js file is linked to the .html and other js code has been working fine.

Comment: It was the placement of my script. I had it before the input elements, replacing it to the bottom of the html body fixed it. Thanks a lot James, all working perfectly!

Comment: @roman74: Yes, it's generally best practice to put any JavaScript (whether between `<script>` tags or in a .js file) that isn't required during the page load at the bottom of the page.Not only does this allow the DOM to be constructed before the any of the JS runs, it also optimizes apparent page load times because the browser renders from the top down so the content will already be rendered while it's waiting on the scripts to load.